# Django changed field name and south but nothing changed : Many-to-many "through"

Tags: python, django, django-south

I change field name from `theaters` to `showtimes`

```
#from
theaters   = models.ManyToManyField(Movie,null=True,blank=True,through="Showtime")
#to
showtimes   = models.ManyToManyField(Movie,null=True,blank=True,through="Showtime")
```

But when I use south to migrate it , nothing happens:

```
$./manage.py schemamigration movie --auto
Nothing seems to have changed.
$./manage.py migrate movie
Running migrations for movie:
- Nothing to migrate.
- Loading initial data for movie.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

I think it's weird, can someone teach me the correct way to migrate it?

Comment: I can't back this up, but I think the `through` argument is used in naming the table if given. Have you tried your current code?

Comment: I try my code.It works well.It seems the changed field didn't influence the current code

Answer (score 0):

There is no change on schema level of database, so south won't perform any action. In django 1.7 and up migrations there will be an migration because django can't tell if any custom (or future) database engine will change something in schema (for example non-SQL databases), south does not have that functionality and it only puts in migrations operations that actually do something with schema in supported databases.